# Insert values in Fluent Migrator with sequence

Tags: c#, sql, fluent-migrator

Is there any way to insert a row using `Fluent Migrator` with my sequence in database?

**Ex. I want execute this command:**

```sql
insert into TEST_TABLE (ID, DUMMY) values (seq_test.nextval, 'TEST')
```

**My sequence:**

```
seq_test
```

**what i have tried:**

```cs
Insert.IntoTable("TEST_TABLE").Row(new { /*Sequence Here*/, DUMMY = "Test" });
```

What can i do to get my sequence next val?

any help would be appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: if you have sequence as list you can do something like

insert into TEST_TABLE (ID, DUMMY)
select seqno, 'test' from dummyDatalist order by seqNo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

insert into TEST_TABLE (ID, DUMMY) values (seq_test.nextval, 'TEST')

If this is oracle Sequence

```
RawSql.Insert("seq_test.nextval from dual"),  should do mix.

Insert.IntoTable("User").Row(new { ID = RawSql.Insert("seq_test.nextval from dual"),DUMMY ='test' });
```

or

```
Insert.IntoTable("User").Row(new { ID = RawSql.Insert("select seq_test.nextval"),DUMMY ='test' });
```

This will result in the Username column being set to the current username. Be aware that by using an sql server specific function like CURRENT_USER that this expression is not portable anymore and will not work against another database (like PostgreSQL).

Raw SQL helper
    When using the Insert.IntoTable expression, or when setting the default column value, all row data that is a string is quoted and saved in the database. If you want to use an sql expression instead then the RawSql helper class is what you need.

```
For example, if I want to use a Microsoft SQL Server function like CURRENT_USER and try to insert like this:

Insert.IntoTable("Users").Row(new { Username = "CURRENT_USER" });
The result will be that the Username column will get the value CURRENT_USER as a string. To execute the function you can use the RawSql.Insert method like this:

Insert.IntoTable("User").Row(new { Username = RawSql.Insert("CURRENT_USER") });
This will result in the Username column being set to the current username. Be aware that by using an sql server specific function like CURRENT_USER that this expression is not portable anymore and will not work against another database (like PostgreSQL).
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Insert.IntoTable("TEST_TABLE ").Row(new { SEQ_NO = RawSql.Insert(0), DUMMY = "TEST"});
```

Comment: Where does this go in the Fluent Migrator that OP is asking specifically for?